# Displaying the number of repeating digits in a fraction

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I would like to check how many repeating digits are in a large fraction, I manually did it for the first few, but the repeating length is too large to manually check.

```
Primorial[n_] := Times @@ Prime[Range[n]]

a = Primorial[0]/EulerPhi[Primorial[0]];
b = Primorial[1]/EulerPhi[Primorial[1]];
c = Primorial[2]/EulerPhi[Primorial[1]];
d = Primorial[3]/EulerPhi[Primorial[2]];
e = Primorial[4]/EulerPhi[Primorial[3]];
f = Primorial[5]/EulerPhi[Primorial[4]];
g = Primorial[6]/EulerPhi[Primorial[5]];
h = Primorial[7]/EulerPhi[Primorial[6]];
i = Primorial[8]/EulerPhi[Primorial[7]];
j = Primorial[9]/EulerPhi[Primorial[8]];
k = Primorial[10]/EulerPhi[Primorial[9]];
l = Primorial[11]/EulerPhi[Primorial[10]];
m = Primorial[12]/EulerPhi[Primorial[11]];
n = Primorial[13]/EulerPhi[Primorial[12]];
o = Primorial[14]/EulerPhi[Primorial[13]];
p = Primorial[15]/EulerPhi[Primorial[14]];

(*
a*b*c*d*e*f*g*h*i*j*k  has 81 long repeating fraction
a*b*c*d*e*f*g*h*i*j*k*l has 729 long repeating fraction
a*b*c*d*e*f*g*h*i*j*k*l*m 59049 long repeating fraction
*)
```

I would like to check the repeating fraction length for
`a*b*c*d*e*f*g*h*i*j*k*l*m*n` and beyond if possible, since
I'm curious if this is related to OEIS sequence: 
81,729,59049,... either: A121858 or A215272

Thanks!

cheers,
Jamie

Comment: can you give one example of what you need, because i didn't get it!

Comment: For `a` and `b` you have `Primorial[i]/EulerPhi[Primorial[i]]` and from `c` on you have `Primorial[i]/EulerPhi[Primorial[i-1]]`. Is this by choice or by mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The period of the decimal expansion of a fraction $p/q$ is equal to the multiplicative order of $10 \mkern-10mu \mod q^*$, where $q = 2^a5^bq^*$ and neither $2$ nor $5$ divides $q^*$.

```
ClearAll[fracPer, vp];
(* p-adic order *)
vp[p_?PrimeQ, n_Integer] := Length@NestWhileList[#/p &, n/p, IntegerQ] - 1;
(* fraction decimal expansion period *)
fracPer[q_Integer] := 0;
fracPer[q_Rational] := Module[{den, p2, p5},
   den = Denominator[q];
   p2 = vp[2, den];
   p5 = vp[5, den];
   den = den/2^p2/5^p5;
   If[den == 1,
    0,
    MultiplicativeOrder[10, den]
    ]
   ];
```

Example:

```
iter[{periods_, frac_, n_}] := {{periods, fracPer[#]}, #, n + 1} &[
   frac*Primorial[n]/EulerPhi[Primorial[Max[1, n - 1]]]];
Flatten@ First@ Nest[iter, {0, Primorial[0]/EulerPhi[Primorial[0]], 0}, 15]
(*  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 27, 729, 59049, 43046721, 31381059609}  *)
```

Comment: those last three terms match https://oeis.org/A013745 Using A038111(n)/A038110 reduced fraction of Primorial/EulerPhi might allow checking more terms.

Comment: @JamieM The above calculates the first 60-70 terms in 1-2 seconds on my machine.  (Just change the `15` to a larger number.)  Assuming checking more terms is what you'd like to do.

Comment: Hi could you paste the first 10 or 20 values after 31381059609?  I tried the two code blocks in one Mathematica notebook but the output is a big list of fractions, so not sure what I did wrong.  Thanks.   Portion of the output I got: 0, fracPer[Primorial[0]^2/(
 EulerPhi[Primorial[0]] EulerPhi[Primorial[1]])]

Comment: @JamieM I pasted the output for `Nest[...,50]` here: https://pastebin.com/raw/tQxTsDzS  -- Maybe try `ClearAll[iter]` and reexecuting the code.  Or restart the kernel.  The code works for me on a fresh kernel with your definition of `Primorial`.

Comment: Thanks!  The three terms after 31381059609, are 3,9,27 times larger than the three terms after 31381059609 in A013745

Comment: For the product with repeating fraction of 27, Taking the product (a * b * c * d * e * f * g * h * i * j) = 3.1637383911850757671315764847766049869476871204719621948744534(465020576131687242798353909) where the repeating fraction 465020576131687242798353909 is a(n-8) = 27 digits long.  There are 61 values 1637383911850757671315764847766049869476871204719621948744534 right of the decimal before the repeating section for n = 10.  I am interested in what that sequence is that starts with 61 for n=10..  Could your code also give the digits and their length before the repeating section?

Comment: @JamieM Not the present code, but the length of the transient part of the decimal expansion of a fraction `x` is given by `m = Ceiling@Log10[x] + Max[vp[2, Denominator@x], vp[5, Denominator@x]]`.  You could then get the digits with `RealDigits[x, 10, m]`. -- BTW, I think you misinterpreted the output of `RealDigits`: The number is not `3.16...` but `3.16... * 10^15`. The output is in the form `{digits, exponent}` and `{{3, 1, 6,..}, 16}` means `0.316... * 10^16`.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I put a draft sequence https://oeis.org/draft/A307388 I'm not sure how to modify your code (I will try) but I think the 61,.. transient part of the decimal expansion is interesting (as well as the actual digits themselves.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you mean? The decimal representation of `a*b*c*d*e*f*g*h*i*j*k` has the repeating digits `{4, 6, 5, 0, 2, 0, 5, 7, 6, 1, 3, 1, 6, 8, 7, 2, 4, 2, 7, 9, 8, 3, 5, 3, 9, 0, 9}`, which is a sequence of length 27:

```
RealDigits[a*b*c*d*e*f*g*h*i*j*k]
```

> {{3, 1, 6, 3, 7, 3, 8, 3, 9, 1, 1, 8, 5, 0, 7, 5, 7, 6, 7, 1, 3, 1, 5,
>      7, 6, 4, 8, 4, 7, 7, 6, 6, 0, 4, 9, 8, 6, 9, 4, 7, 6, 8, 7, 1, 2, 
>     0, 4, 7, 1, 9, 6, 2, 1, 9, 4, 8, 7, 4, 4, 5, 3, 
>     4, {4, 6, 5, 0, 2, 0, 5, 7, 6, 1, 3, 1, 6, 8, 7, 2, 4, 2, 7, 9, 8, 
>      3, 5, 3, 9, 0, 9}}, 16}

You get this length from

```
RealDigits[a*b*c*d*e*f*g*h*i*j*k][[1, -1]] // Length
```

> 27

```
RealDigits[a*b*c*d*e*f*g*h*i*j*k*l][[1, -1]] // Length
```

> 729

```
RealDigits[a*b*c*d*e*f*g*h*i*j*k*l*m][[1, -1]] // Length
```

> 59049

---

compact code:

```
Primorial[n_] := Times @@ Prime[Range[n]]
pp[i_Integer /; 0 <= i <= 1] := Primorial[i]/EulerPhi[Primorial[i]]
pp[i_Integer /; i >= 2] := Primorial[i]/EulerPhi[Primorial[i - 1]]

Table[Length[RealDigits[Product[pp[i], {i, 0, n}]][[1, -1]]], {n, 0, 13}]
```

> {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 27, 729, 59049, 43046721}

Comment: Thanks yes, that matches https://oeis.org/A215272